# Segmentation fault while running turtlesim_node

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the beginner tutorials for ROS.
However, when attempting to run turtlesim by using the command `rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node` (after `roscore`being run in a different terminal) I run into a segmentation fault with the following message:

> [ INFO] [1540211266.549429837]:
> Starting turtlesim with node name
> /turtlesim [ INFO]
> [1540211266.558342044]: Spawning
> turtle [turtle1] at x=[5.544445],
> y=[5.544445], theta=[0.000000]
> Segmentation fault

I tried uninstalling and installing the turtlesim package, but this didn't work.
What can I do about it?

I am using ROS Kinetic on a virtual machine running 64-bit Ubuntu, under Oracle VM Virtualbox.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306421/segmentation-fault-while-running-turtlesim_node/) by [erdanielx](https://answers.ros.org/users/38146/erdanielx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-10-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-22**:
When reporting `SEGFAULT`s, always include information about the platform you try to run things on, and how you installed ROS (from sources (ie: compiling yourself) or binary pkgs). If you used any, link to tutorials.

**Comment by [erdanielx](https://answers.ros.org/users/38146/erdanielx/) on 2018-10-22**:
I downloaded a .ova file given to me by one of my professors with ROS pre-installed on it, I don't really know what method he used to install it. After doing that I followed the tutorials [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials), starting from point 1.1.2 (Navigating the ROS Filesystem).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-22**:
It is likely then that the ROS pkgs in your VM (always mention the fact that you're using a VM!) and the pkgs you installed to follow the tutorials have gone out-of-sync.

Try upgrading *all* ROS pkgs inside the VM and see if that helps.

Partial upgrades are not supported by ROS.

**Comment by [erdanielx](https://answers.ros.org/users/38146/erdanielx/) on 2018-10-23**:
I decided to install a new VM and install ROS on it myself, I found that better than upgrading all ROS pkgs. Now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By re-installing ROS on a new VM I was able to solve the problem.

---

Originally posted by [erdanielx](https://answers.ros.org/users/38146/erdanielx/) with karma: 16 on 2018-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0